# Vincular datos desde Onedrive con R Server

Tags: r, rstudio

estoy trabajando desde **R server** con un servidor linux y necesito obtener datos desde onedrive y no he podido vincular estos archivos, alguien que me pueda guiar por favor.

Comment: Hola, bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour], leas [ask] y agregues un [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Saludos

Comment: Con onedrive puedes "sincronizar" una carpeta y sus archivos a una carpeta local, con esto la carga de  datos no deja de ser la misma que harías con cualquier archivo local. Trata de ampliar tu pregunta y lee los enlaces que te pasaron. Suerte.

Comment: el problema es que el R lo trabajo desde un servidor externo (es un link de una maquina linux), si fuera el studio de escritorio no es problema por la sincronización de los archivos, entonces, no puedo acceder desde este servidor a las carpetas, tanto para almacenar como para leer data, tengo que ir creando directorios y no me sirve por los cambios de data.